# Webform ID not shown in debug output?

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I created a new module to extend the webform module for custom submission hooks:

```
function mywebform_extra_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_213') {
        $first = array_shift($form['#submit']);
        array_unshift($form['#submit'], $first, 'mywebform_extra_submit_213');
    }
}
```

I have the webform module installed and I created a webform that has a node id of 213.

When I try to output the $form_id variable, the value shown is nothing indicative of a webform and instead showing "search_form_block" as the form ID?

what is the error here? I pulled it straight from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174165/drupal-7-webform-submit-hook).

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module.
2. Use the dpm() function, it will print out `$form_id` for *all forms* on any page you visit.

   ```
   function mywebform_extra_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     dpm($form_id);
   }
   ```